# Angles between lateral faces of any rectangular-based pyramid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

I was just wondering if anyone had any idea how to solve this problem:

What is the angle between lateral faces of a rectangular-based pyramid with length *a*, width *b*, and height *h*, in terms of *a*, *b* and *h*?

Any responses are much appreciated.

Comment: What level of math do you have? The most direct approach is via vectors and dot products, but that's a bit above trigonometry.

Comment: And I assume the orthogonal projection of the apex of the pyramid coincides with the center of the rectangle, making the pyramid symmetric? If so, and you are ok with vectors, check  out Aretino's solution...

Answer (score 2):

Set up a coordinate system such that pyramid vertex is $V=(0,0,h)$ and base vertices are $A=(b/2,a/2,0)$, $B=(-b/2,a/2,0)$, $C=(-b/2,-a/2,0)$, 
$D=(b/2,-a/2,0)$.

A vector $N_1$ perpendicular to face $VAB$ (and directed outwards) can be found by
$$
N_1=(A-V)\times(B-V)=
\left({b\over2},{a\over2},-h\right)\times\left(-{b\over2},{a\over2},-h\right)
=\left(0,hb,{ab\over2}\right).
$$
Analogously, one can find a vector $N_2$ perpendicular to face $VAD$ and directed inwards:
$$
N_2=-(D-V)\times(A-V)=
-\left({b\over2},-{a\over2},-h\right)\times\left({b\over2},{a\over2},-h\right)
=-\left(ha,0,{ab\over2}\right).
$$
Angle $\theta$ between those faces is also the angle between $N_1$ and $N_2$, so it can be found by
$$
\cos\theta={N_1\cdot N_2\over|N_1|\cdot |N_2|}=
{-1\over\sqrt{1+4h^2/a^2}\sqrt{1+4h^2/b^2}}.
$$

Comment: can you clarify why you have one vector directed outwards and the other directed inwards?  Shouldn't they both be pointing outward (or inward with the same result)?  (This only results in a change of the -1 to 1 for the numerator.)  A good thought experiment is to look at the equation as h approaches infinity (a rectangular box) and as h becomes 0 (a flat surface).

Comment: @Borgboy Indeed: as $h\to0$ we should have $\theta\to\pi$, so the formula has the right sign. Notice that $\theta$ is the angle between two LATERAL faces.

Comment: how would you know the correct orientation of the normal vectors without looking at the equation? thanks

Comment: @wwjrmmr I don't know which equation you are alluding to, but all you need is making a sketch of the pyramid with the given vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Brief hints:

half-diagonal = HD=$\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}$

tetrahedron slant length = L= $ \sqrt {h^2+HD^2}  $

Calculate $h1,h2$ as altitudes of lateral isosceles triangles sides as all the three sides are known.

Basis of calculation:

To find *Dihedral Angle* between normals of adjacent faces containing $h1,h2$. Using $c,s$ short for $\cos, \sin, $

$$ s_{\alpha}= \frac{a}{2 L};\,s_{\beta}= \frac{b}{2 L};\, \tag1$$

As pointed by Mick,feet of perpendiculars should have an offset as now shown in the diagram. To consider this a development ( unfolded view ) of two neighboring sides is included that builds to the tetrahedral inter-hedral angle as dihedral angle.

coordinates $A= A_1$

$$ L[ c_{2 \alpha} ,s_{2\alpha},0] \tag2$$

coordinates $ A_2$ after rotation by angle$\gamma$ with side $OP$ as hinge

$$ L[ c_{2 \alpha} ,-s_{2\alpha} \cos \gamma,s_{2\alpha} s_ \gamma \tag3$$

coordinates $ B$
$$ L[ c_{2 \beta} ,-s_{2\beta},0] \tag4$$

Now let us find distance $A_2$ after folding to B

$$d^2_{B-A_2} /L^2= a^2+b^2  \tag5 $$

$$[  ( c_{2 \alpha} - c_{2 \beta} )^2 -
 (s_{2 \alpha} c_\gamma + s_{2 \beta} )^2+  s_{2 \alpha} s_\gamma )^2= \frac{a^2+b^2 }{L^2}\tag6 $$

which simplifies  further to

$$  \frac{a^2+b^2 }{L^2}= 1 + \cos 2\alpha (\cos 2 \alpha+ 2\cos  2 \beta  )+\sin  2 \alpha (\sin 2 \alpha +2 \cos \gamma \sin 2 \beta  ) \tag7$$

$$  \frac{a^2+b^2 }{2 L^2}= 1 + \cos 2\alpha \cos  2 \beta +  \cos \gamma\, \sin  2 \alpha \sin 2 \beta  \tag8$$

from which $\gamma$ can be found. That is one method. Hope you can check if there are no errors or some trig simplification can still be effected.

[image]

Comment: The angle between planes EBD and EDC is the angle formed by $h_1$ and $h_2$ provided that (1) they meet the line of intersection ED at the same point; and (2) $h_1 \bot ED$ and $h_2 \bot ED$. Is there anyway to guarantee $h_1$ and $h_2$ have met both of the required conditions?

Answer (score 1):

@Aretino's coordinate/vector approach might be the most accessible, but it's worth mentioning a couple of others.

---

Given any three-faced "corner", one can determine the dihedral angles from the face angles (or vice-versa) using an appropriate [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines). For the problem at hand, with this configuration ...

[image]

... we can write ...

> $$\cos\angle APB = \cos\angle APC \cos \angle BPC + \sin\angle APC \sin\angle BPC \cos\angle PC \tag{$\star$}$$

where "$\angle PC$" indicates the dihedral angle along $\overline{PC}$. In our rectangular pyramid, $\angle APB$ is a right angle, so that $(\star)$ reduces to

> $$\cos\angle PC = -\cot\angle APC \cot\angle BPC \tag{1}$$

Labeling a few distances, including $m$ and $n$ as altitudes of faces $\triangle CPA$ and $\triangle CPB$, ...

[image]

... we have ...

$$\cos \angle PC = -\frac{a/2}{m} \cdot \frac{b/2}{n} = -\frac{ab}{4mn} \tag{2}$$

Invoking Pythagoras,
$$m^2 = \left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 + h^2 = \frac{1}{4}\left( b^2 + 4 h^2 \right) \qquad\qquad n^2 = \frac{1}{4}\left( a^2 + 4 h^2 \right)$$
we have

> $$\cos\angle PC = -\frac{ab}{\sqrt{(a^2 + 4 h^2 )(b^2 + 4 h^2 )}} \tag{3}$$

---

I would be remiss not to also mention a solution using a *hedronometric* ("area-based") Law of Cosines for Tetrahedra. In particular:

> $$\begin{align}
> &|\triangle PAC|^2 + |\triangle PBC|^2 - 2 |\triangle PAC||\triangle PBC|\cos\angle PC \\
> = &|\triangle ACB|^2 + |\triangle APB|^2 - 2|\triangle ACB||\triangle APB|\cos\angle AB
> \end{align} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

As dihedral $\angle AB$ is a right angle, isolating $\cos \angle PC$ gives:

$$\cos\angle PC = \frac{|\triangle PAC|^2 + |\triangle PBC|^2 - |\triangle ACB|^2 - |\triangle APB|^2}{2|\triangle PAC||\triangle PBC|} \tag{4}$$
Then, since ...
$$
|\triangle PAC| = \frac12 a m = \frac14 a \sqrt{b^2 + 4 h^2} \qquad\qquad
|\triangle PBC| = \frac12 b n = \frac14 b \sqrt{a^2 + 4 h^2 }$$
$$
|\triangle ACB| = \frac12 h |\overline{AB}| = \frac12 h \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \qquad\qquad |\triangle APB| = \frac12 ab$$

... we find that $(4)$ ultimately reduces to $(3)$. $\square$

Comment: Unless I mistaken, the terms in the denominator for (3) fall under separate square root functions, not one as shown.  As such, (3) reduces to the solution presented by @Aretino.

Comment: @Borgboy: $\sqrt{p\cdot q} = \sqrt{p}\cdot\sqrt{q}$ (for non-negative $p$ and $q$). And, I didn't mean to imply that my ultimate answer differs from Aretino's, just my *path(s) to* that answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I've been staring at this to long tonight.